# Toggle one div at a time

Tags: jquery, click, toggle, containers, jquery-masonry

I've got this code copied and pasted multiple times with different menu-item IDs. Is there a way to simplify it and/or toggle one container at a time? Thank You

```
$('#menu-item-1 a, #TH').click(function () {    

var $container = $('#boxes');

    setTimeout(function(){ $container.masonry() }, 400);

var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');


var toggle_switch = $(this);
$(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function () {
    if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {

    } else {

    }
});    
});

$('#menu-item-2 a, #FM').click(function () {

var $container = $('#boxes');

    setTimeout(function(){ $container.masonry() }, 400);

var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');

var toggle_switch = $(this);
$(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function () {
    if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {

    } else {

    }
});
});
```

Comment: Use a common class in your selector. Your code inside the actual click handler looks fine as it is.

Comment: As your code within the `click` function is identical you can just combine the selectors into one `$('#menu-item-1 a, #menu-item-2 a, #FM, #TH').click...`

Comment: They all toggle different masonry blocks content and I have it copied about 20 times. How will a common class help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.ClassOfClickableObjects').click(function () {  

    var $container = $('#boxes');
    setTimeout(function(){ $container.masonry() }, 400);
    var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');
    var toggle_switch = $(this);

    $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function () {
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') {

        } else {

        }
    });    
});
```

Is what Blazemonger is suggesting...

Comment: I guess that works, is there a way so when I toggle one the other close?

Comment: When i say hide the object disappears completely, I'm sorry its morning and I'm fairly new at this. Thanks for all the help.